# Invalid column index , update using PreparedStatement

Tags: java, jdbc, oracle11g

I am updating table using PreparedStatement

the following code works perfectly

```
pst = conn.prepareStatement("UPDATE playjdbc SET jlname ='javafx10new' WHERE jfname = 'java10'");
int i = pst.executeUpdate();
```

but when i tried like this it throwing exception

```
 pst = conn.prepareStatement("UPDATE playjdbc SET jlname ='javafx10new' WHERE jfname =?");
 pst.setString(2, "java10"); // yeah second column is jfname

 int i = pst.executeUpdate();
```

stacktrace :

```
java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column index
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.setStringInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:5330)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.setString(OraclePreparedStatement.java:5318)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.setString(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:282)
    at com.indus.database.EmployeeDTO.updateData(EmployeeDTO.java:114)
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

2 in following refers to the position of the question mark in query string, not to the position of column in database table and not to the order of column names used in query:

```
 pst.setString(2, "java10"); // yeah second column is jfname
```

Use 1 instead.

```
pst.setString(1, "java10"); // first question mark is jfname
```

Answer (score 1):

Please go through the `setString()` method specs:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setString%28int,%20java.lang.String%29

The correct approach is :

```
pst = conn.prepareStatement("UPDATE playjdbc SET jlname ='javafx10new' WHERE jfname =?");
pst.setString(1, "java10"); 

int i = pst.executeUpdate();
```