# passing data parameters to updata SQL table

Tags: java, sql, swing

A user enters in his information via 8 JTextFields. This information is passed via parameters into the updateUser method and the method updates the SQL table with this information. This is what I am currently trying to do although when User presses update button, no changes are made to the database table

**retrieve user data, create UserOperation and call updateUser method**

```
   String userName = textFieldUserName.getText();
                String userPassword = textField_1.getText();
                String securityQuestion = textFieldSecQuestion.getText();
                String securityAnswer = textFieldAnswer.getText();
                String email = textFieldEmail.getText();
                String fName = textFieldName.getText();
                String phoneNumber = textFieldPhone.getText();
                String department = textFieldDepartment.getText();

                UserOperations userOperations = new UserOperations();
                userOperations.updateUser(userName, userPassword, securityQuestion, securityAnswer, email, fName, phoneNumber, department);
```

**the updateUser method**

```
     public void updateUser (String userName, String userPassword, String securityQuestion, String securityAnswer, String email, String fName, String phoneNumber, String department)
    {

        try
        {
            String sql = "UPDATE systeuser SET username = ?,userpassword = ?,securityquestion = ?,securityanswer = ?,email = ?,fname = ?,phonenumber = ?,department = ? WHERE username = ?";
              stmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
              stmt.setString (1, userName);
              stmt.setString (2, userPassword);
              stmt.setString (3, securityQuestion);
              stmt.setString (4, securityAnswer);
              stmt.setString (5, email);
              stmt.setString (6, fName);
              stmt.setString (7, phoneNumber);
              stmt.setString (8, department);
              stmt.setString (9, userName);
              stmt.executeUpdate( );
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace ( );

        }

    }
```

Comment: Remove the All quotes before '?' when you Create statement using PrepareStatement , It doesn not require any quotes, taht why we used SetString and setInt in the statement.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Invalid column index , update using PreparedStatement](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9384804/invalid-column-index-update-using-preparedstatement)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its because of the single quotes placed around the `?`. You need not give those single quotes, since you're doing this:-

```
stmt.setString(1, userName); // setString says that this parameter is a String
```

Thus, the single quote generally used to enclose `String` in a query is not needed in your case.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have removed the single quotes from around the ?. I no longer get the error upon pressing the update button, although when I check in the database myself, the update did not happen. can you see anything wrong with the SQL statement itself?

Comment: There are 2 things which make me wonder why are you doing those! Firstly, why update the `username` based on which you're updating the other `fields`? Next, why call both `executeQuery()` & `executeUpdate()`. Just the `executeUpdate()` should do! Look into this and see if it makes a difference! Also, the name of the `table`, I guess its not proper or may be a typo here!

Comment: I have edited my main post. 1. I don't really understand your 1st question, i am using the username in the SQL statement to update the correct row of the table. 2.Thanks for pointing that out, I have removed the executeQuery(). The name of the table is correct, I already have a systemuser table in another project

Comment: Why do this? `UPDATE systeuser SET username = ? ... WHERE username = ?`. Why do you want to `SET` your `username` as well?

Comment: to give the user the option of changing his username, is this incorrect? here is a picture of the gui http://gyazo.com/6ed2e0759f361892acb8fa30f4dcb0c0

Comment: That's the mistake here! The user enters a new `username` and you're using that new `username` itself to update! Since it never existed in your table, it can't find a row for that username and hence, nothing was updated! Hope you get the point here. You can change the username, but you need to give the old username in the where condition and the new username in the `set`!

Answer (score 0):

Don't put the question marks used the query parameters in quotes. Instead, use:

```
UPDATE systeuser SET username = ?, userpassword = ?, ...
```